# Square Checkout API - Can you change the "Place Order" button text?

Tags: api, checkout, square

I would like to change it to something like "Check Out" or "Pay Amount."

Answer (score 1):

No - the Square Checkout API isn't customizable. If you want more customization, I recommend using the Square Payment Form.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/overview